# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 Error

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm writing a simple update-password page (studying purposes). The page consist of two text-box controls that will allow the user to enter their new password, followed by confirming their password by entering it into the second text-box control and finally clicking the submit bottom to update their password in the table stored in a database. My problem is that I receive the following error upon button-click: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 Error.

This is the code in behind he button:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox2.Text = TextBox3.Text Then

            Dim myConnectionString As String
            myConnectionString = "myDbIIConnectionString1"
            Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
            myConnection.Open()

            Dim mySQLQuery As String
            mySQLQuery = "UPDATE myTb SET password  VALUES (@password)"

            Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, myConnection)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox3.Text)
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            myCommand = Nothing
            myConnection.Close()
            myConnection = Nothing

            Label2.Text = "Your Password has been changed"
        Else
            Label2.Text = "Retype your Password"
        End If

        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End Sub
```

Could someone assist me as to what I'm missing here? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your update query . Correct it as :

```
mySQLQuery = "UPDATE myTb SET password=@password"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error; Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; I should have been using  configurationmanager.connectionstrings["the name goes here"]. to access my connection string.